# Mobile templates based on user-agent in django ensuring thread safety

Tags: django, django-templates, thread-safety, mobile-website, django-middleware

I am developing the mobile version of my website, so thought of using user-agent as the criteria for serving different templates for mobile and web version.
I successfully read the user-agent information from nginx and passed it as header to gunicorn server.

Then I created a middleware which reads this header and changes the templates directory in settings file. This seemed to work initially but then I realized that there is race condition happening as this method is not thread safe. (I should have thought of it before-hand).

So I started thinking of other alternatives. One solution was to overwrite the render method of django to include "dirs" parameter based on request header. But then I found out that the "dirs" parameter is deprecated. Following is the reference link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/shortcuts/#render
So even this will not work.

Another solution is to have different template names for mobile and web and load them accordingly. However I don't want to do this and want to keep the templates directory structure exactly same for both web and mobile.

There has to be a way to just overwrite the template directory. This will give me an advantage of falling back on web version of templates if its missing in mobile templates directory.

Any advise on how to achieve this will be helpful.

This is how my templates are organized.

```
App1
   templates
       App1
           index.html
           catalog.html
App2
   templates
       App2
           about.html
```

And in the project directory(not part of the app folder), there is a mobile templates folder which has the following structure

```
mobile-templates
    App1
        index.html
    App2
        about.html
```

Thanks
Anurag

Comment: How about modifying the `request` object to add the directory name? Then `render` can render the file by attaching the path to this `request.template_dir `variable.

Comment: @SudhanshuShekhar - Even if I modify the request object, how will render function take the directory name automatically? I checked the source code also, and didn't find that request.template_dir is used by render function. Don't know if I missed something, please clarify.
If you mean to pre-append directory name in my render function, then falling back on web version will not work.

Comment: I was thinking about something like : `render(request, ["app/template/t_mobile.html", "app/template/t.html"], context)` . You can use the `request.template_dir` to decide whether to add the `t_mobile.html` as an option or not.

Comment: I tried that already, but it doesn't work until I define the mobile template directory in settings file. And once I do that, order of templates I specify in render function doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how I would organize my templates:**

1. Make two directories inside `templates` dir - `mobile` and `desktop`.
2. Keep mobile templates in `mobile` dir and desktop templates in `desktop`.

This way you won't have to rename the templates.

---

**And here's how I would render them:**

1. Read User-Agent in a middleware.
2. Set an attribute on `request` called `template_prefix` whose value will either be `mobile` or `desktop`, depending on the User-Agent. Eg:

   ```
   def process_request(self, request):
       # read user agent and determine if 
       # request is from mobile or desktop
       # ...
       if mobile_user_agent:
           request.template_prefix = 'mobile'
       else:
           request.template_prefix = 'desktop'
   ```
3. In your views, use `request.template_prefix` before template names. Eg:

   ```
   def home(request):
       ...
       template = request.template_prefix + '/home.html'
       return render(request, template)
   ```

This will render the templates from either `mobile` or `desktop` dirs depending on the value `template_prefix` attribute.

---

**UPDATE** (according to question edit):

Looking at how your templates are organized, I'd do this:

1. Middleware:

   Only set `template_prefix` for mobile requests.

   ```
   def process_request(self, request):
       if mobile_user_agent:
           request.template_prefix = 'mobile-templates'
       else:
           request.template_prefix = '' # set an empty string
   ```
2. Views:

   Use `os.path.join`; catch `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception.

   ```
   import os.path
   from django.template.loader import get_template
   from django.template.base import TemplateDoesNotExist

   def index(request):
       try:
           template = os.path.join(request.template_prefix, 'App1/index.html')
           get_template(template)
       except TemplateDoesNotExist:
           template = 'App1/index.html'

       return render(request, template)
   ```

I've tested this and it works. But writing a `try...except` block in every view seems redundant. If I come up with a better solution, I will update.

Comment: This will throw error for the fallback case as there will be very few mobile templates compared to desktop ones. And if mobile template is not found, it should fallback to desktop template.

Comment: @anurag In that case you can use `request.template_prefix` in only those views where you want to render different templates. If there are no mobile template for that view, manually use `desktop` prefix. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is I will not know if the template exist or not. So I will have to either check if file is present or modify my render function whenever a mobile template is created.
I am able to achieve this without modifying the render function by using parameter "dirs", but because its deprecated I am looking for a proper way. Can't understand why is it deprecated.

Comment: thanks @xyres, this should work. I need to test it as my current template structure is a bit different. Will revert back after verifying. I have also updated the question with my current template structure.

Comment: @anurag [Since Django 1.8, `select_template` works differently](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/#get-template-and-select-template). Therefore, it won't work like I've described in my answer. I will try and update.

Comment: I modified your solution a bit, and its working for me without having to put try except statements. I created a customRender which calls the render function internally. In the render function, I modified the template path based on whether its mobile or not and pass on list of templates in the appropriate order to the render function.
return render(request, ['mobile/'+template_name, template_name],context)

Comment: You can use that try catch in a middleware in process_response to render that not found template.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it isn't possible to this out of the box right now. If you really want to follow this architecture, you will have to write your own custom loader and also figure out a way to pass the request/indicator to let it know its a mobile request.

It's not too tough to write the loader (just see the Django filesystem loader, if the request is from mobile, loop through all the templates_dirs and add the proper suffix to it, so that you include mobile dirs too).

However the biggest challenge as I see it is being able to pass a dynamic parameter to it (indicating that this is a mobile request). You may store this param in the session or modify the template name before passing it to the custom renderer (The renderer will remove this indicator part and get the template) .

Comment: Its not about following a particular architecture, this is more of a problem statement for which I am looking for a proper solution. I can create the loader, but as you said that passing the dynamic parameter is a pain as loader methods don't get access to request object. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#custom-loaders
And modifying the template name before loading the template and then reading it and undoing the modification done previously seems to be even more confusing.

Comment: Seems like a generic issue, not sure how people solve this