# Django middleware redirect based on user agent

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm trying to make redirect based on user agent.
Right now I have in views.py:

```
class IndexRedirectView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_agent = get_user_agent(self.request)
        if user_agent.is_pc:
            return reverse_lazy("main:index")
        else:
            return reverse_lazy("main:mobile_index")
```

I check the user agent only on main page, but I need to do this on any page (for any article page, for example) and redirect user to desktop or mobile version of the web-site.

How to do it properly? Maybe, by writing own middleware like this:

```
class UserAgentMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if user_agent.is_pc:
            HttpResponseRedirect('desktop version')
        else:
            HttpResponseRedirect('mobile version')
```

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: I answered a similar question a few years ago. You may find it helpful:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35955026/1925257

Comment: @xyres Is it possible instead of template_name, set url (something like `reverse(main:index)`)? (I'm using django 2+)

Comment: If you're doing that, won't that mean you'll have to maintain two separate views for mobile and desktop? That's too much code duplication and switching templates during render time seems a far better approach to me.

Comment: BTW, you can issue redirects from a middleware the way you're trying to do. Hint: use [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) to find a matching url pattern from the incoming request url like - `/path/to/page/`. Then issue a redirect according to the `url_name`.

Comment: @xyres Yes, switching templates is much better. I'll try this way. Thank you so much.